# Removing duplicates based on two columns while deleting inconsistent data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  2  4  1    
3  3  5  0
4  3  5  0
```

where the first 2 columns ('a' and 'b') are IDs while the last one ('c') is a validation (0 = neg, 1 = pos). I do know how to remove duplicates based on the values of the first 2 columns, however in this case I would also like to get rid of inconsistent data i.e. duplicated data validated both as positive and negative. So for example the first 2 rows are duplicated but inconsistent hence I should remove the entire record, while the last 2 rows are both duplicated and consistent so I'd keep one of the records. The expected result sholud be:

```
   a  b  c
0  2  4  1
1  3  5  0
```

The real dataframe can have more than two duplicates per group and
as you can see also the index has been changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First filter rows by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) for get only unique values groups with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df[df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
           .drop_duplicates(['a','b'])
           .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  2  4  1
1  3  5  0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].transform('nunique'))
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks jezrael your answer is nearly perfect, it just misses the last part of my request about the index, but it's really a very easy thing. I just added .reset_index(drop=True) at the end!!

Comment: @Simosini - Some problem with solution?